# What file defines the relation between front-end and methods in the code-behind file?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, get

When I have a form element in the view:
`create.cshtml`

```html
<form method="get">
    ...whatever
</form>
```

and we have a model in the code-behind file:
`create.cshtml.cs`

```cs
public class CreateModel : PageModel 
{
    //...whatever
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

the form will call `OnGet()`. I understand that this is a standard and is followed in most frameworks, but that means it must be defined somewhere in .NET. What file defines this standard and if we can, can we change it (for understanding's sake)?

Comment: From my understanding it doesn't have to be a form. A page can trigger `OnGet` too. It's more like an eventlistener. If you look at a default CRUD-page, you'll see that POST request also can get intercepted by that method (of course now `OnPost`).

Comment: No, all I want to know is that where is it configured that the framework is to call `OnGet` named method in its page model class? Because `OnGet` is a completely user-defined and user-declared method. It is not inherited from the PageModel class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon initialisation, a Razor Pages web-app builds a collection of [`PageApplicationModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageapplicationmodel?view=aspnetcore-5.0) instances, which describe the Razor Pages from the web-app and their associated handler methods.

To understand more about how this works, have a look at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultPageApplicationModelProvider.cs#L152-L164) for the `DefaultPageApplicationModelProvider`'s `PopulateHandlerMethods` method:

> ```
> internal void PopulateHandlerMethods(PageApplicationModel pageModel)
> {
>     var methods = pageModel.HandlerType.GetMethods();
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
>     {
>         var handler = _pageApplicationModelPartsProvider
>             .CreateHandlerModel(methods[i]);
>
>         if (handler != null)
>         {
>             pageModel.HandlerMethods.Add(handler);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Here, we can see that the framework enumerates the Razor Page's class's methods and calls the `DefaultPageApplicationModelPartsProvider`'s [`CreateHandlerModel`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/baca18bdc85e24cb2ea13681c41fb6b4790e8169/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultPageApplicationModelPartsProvider.cs#L34-L72) method for each of these. `CreateHandlerModel` determines if the method is a handler (e.g. it's `public`, not `static`) and then parses the method name to determine its HTTP method, handler name, etc. This parsing takes place in [`TryParseHandlerMethod`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/baca18bdc85e24cb2ea13681c41fb6b4790e8169/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultPageApplicationModelPartsProvider.cs#L221-L272):

> ```
> internal static bool TryParseHandlerMethod(
>     string methodName, out string httpMethod, out string handler)
> {
>     httpMethod = null;
>     handler = null;
>
>     // Handler method names always start with "On"
>     if (!methodName.StartsWith("On") || methodName.Length <= "On".Length)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     // Now we parse the method name according to our conventions to
>     // determine the required HTTP method and optional 'handler name'.
>     // Valid names look like:
>     //  - OnGet
>     //  - OnPost
>     //  - OnFooBar
>     //  - OnTraceAsync
>     //  - OnPostEditAsync
>
>     var start = "On".Length;
>     var length = methodName.Length;
>     if (methodName.EndsWith("Async", StringComparison.Ordinal))
>     {
>         length -= "Async".Length;
>     }
>
>     if (start == length)
>     {
>         // There are no additional characters. This is "On" or "OnAsync".
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     // The http method follows "On" and is required to be at least one
>     // character. We use casing to determine where it ends.
>     var handlerNameStart = start + 1;
>     for (; handlerNameStart < length; handlerNameStart++)
>     {
>         if (char.IsUpper(methodName[handlerNameStart]))
>         {
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     httpMethod = methodName.Substring(start, handlerNameStart - start);
>
>     // The handler name follows the http method and is optional.
>     // It includes everything up to the end excluding the "Async" suffix
>     // (if present).
>     handler = handlerNameStart == length
>         ? null
>         : methodName.Substring(handlerNameStart, length - handlerNameStart);
>     return true;
> }
> ```

This code does a good job of explaining itself, but ultimately it parses out the HTTP method and an optional handler name.

Finally, the framework creates an instance of [`PageHandlerModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pagehandlermodel?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to hold the extracted information. With this information in place, the routing system is able to select a handler based on an incoming request. This selection logic gets handled by the [`DefaultPageHandlerMethodSelector`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/baca18bdc85e24cb2ea13681c41fb6b4790e8169/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/Infrastructure/DefaultPageHandlerMethodSelector.cs) class.

The `DefaultPageApplicationModelPartsProvider` class implements the `IPageApplicationModelPartsProvider` interface and gets resolved using DI. You could create your own implementation of `IPageApplicationModelPartsProvider` and replace the default implementation, which would allow you to perform your own method name parsing, for example.

To use a custom implementation, e.g. `MyCustomPageApplicationModelPartsProvider`, add something like the following to `ConfigureServices`, ideally before the call to `AddRazorPages`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPageApplicationModelPartsProvider,
    MyCustomPageApplicationModelPartsProvider>();
```

---

> In addition to explaining how the framework finds the handlers, the answer also should explain how does the framework define one file as a code-behind for another.

The connection between a page and its `PageModel` is made using the `@model` directive in the .cshtml file. e.g. In `Index.cshtml` you'll see `@model IndexModel`. You can rename `Index.cshtml.cs` to `SomethingElse.cs` and it'll still work, so the file-naming is more of a convention.